# How use attribute from include model to make a where condition?

Tags: typescript, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want use an attribute from include model on my query,I use sequelize and sequelize-typescript and some previous versions I used literals to injecting sql variables to my query-model and worked but these method has been parched because it was a SQL Injection vulnerability  and now, I don't know what use for access to attributes of my include model

I want use cve_agenda attribute for evaluate with invitados.cve_funcionario on the same level of or operator

i use these:

````js
M_AG_EVENTOS.findAll({
                where: {
                        $or: [
                          cve_agenda: cve_agenda, ORM.instance.seql.literal(`"invitados"."cve_funcionario" =${cve_funcionario}`),
ORM.instance.seql.literal(`"comisionado"."cve_funcionario" = ${cve_funcionario}`)]
                } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your example SQL injection is possible because you are passing parameters directly in the query string. The best way to protect agains SQL injection is to use prepared statements. Then SQL query and parameters are separated and database read parameters as text (so even if param value would be `DELETE FROM users` it won't be executed, just treated as a string). With `Sequelize` you can do it by using [Bind parameters](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#bind-parameter).

But back to your question, here is an example how query with `include` looks:

```
ModelA.findAll({
  where: { name: 'John' },
  include: [{
    model: ModelB,
    as: 'modelB',
    where: { active: true },
  }],
});
```